# Dependency for Spring-cache.xsd in spring-MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-cache, ehcache-3

I am trying to implement caching with the Ehcache and made the following configuration in the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

but I am getting "internal server error" when trying to invoke the REST API.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

  <cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />
  <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager">
    <bean class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:cacheManagerUri="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    </property>
  </bean>
```

When i click on "http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd" , it shows HTTP 404 Error in Eclipse web browser, Is this is the issue?

How can I resolve this issue?